# Wifi disconnecting after some time in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, REL8822 CE

Tags: drivers, 22.04, network-manager, pci

I have a problem with wifi connection, the wifi is disconnecting after some time. The wifi is connecting if I restart the pc and after some time disconnecting again.

I ran the command:

```
sudo dmsg
```

I got the output regarding network:

```
[ 3213.081109] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: mac power on failed
[ 3213.081113] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to power on mac
[ 3215.125625] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[ 3215.125644] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: mac power on failed
[ 3215.125648] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to power on mac
[ 3217.149774] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[ 3217.149792] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: mac power on failed
[ 3217.149796] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to power on mac
[ 3229.030430] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[ 3229.030448] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: mac power on failed
[ 3229.030452] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to power on mac
[ 3231.056196] rtw_8822ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
```

If I run the command:

```
sudo ip link show wlp4s0
```

I got output as:

```
3: wlp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:c0:a6:57:3c:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I've tried using command:

```
sudo ip link set wlp4s0 up
```

I've tried restarting the network with the commmand:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

But It didn't work.

My pc is Azus TUF FX505